# JSON array to Swift Array

Tags: swift

I'm fairly new to Swift and trying to get a JSON array that comes back from Alamofire into a normal Swift array.

```
var dpoParamArr     = JSON([])
//Alamofire code here and I get the value back below which is Parameters
self.dpoParamArr    = JSON(dictMain)["Parameters"] 

print(self.dpoParamArr.arrayValue.map({($0.dictionaryValue["name"]?.stringValue)!}))
print(self.dpoParamArr.arrayValue.map({($0.dictionaryValue["value"]?.stringValue)!}))
```

This is the print result:
["PAY_REQUEST_ID", "CHECKSUM"]
["5FB1DDBB-D637-3DC3-C0AF-288EFF98012C", "4FD856821E0F6D238F8346175227FF04"]

How do I get my array to have a key and value

```
 "Parameters": [
    {
      "name": "PAY_REQUEST_ID",
      "value": "94DEE72B-F75C-453F-1280-F1B26BBFD98E"
    },
    {
      "name": "CHECKSUM",
      "value": "9171405E05C9C9B7D4B6FF497FC4AE50"
    }
  ]
```

My end goal is to get the name and value variables for both JSON nodes.

Comment: "I get my array to have a key and value" Are you sure you want an array, not a array of Dictionary? Could you show, if you created it yourself, what it would be?

Comment: Sorry but not clear on the terminology. All I want to do is for loop through my JSON(dictMain)["Parameters"] to get the name and value for the two JSON nodes.

Comment: I need the values for a https form:
                                postFormHtml += "<input type='hidden' name='PAY_REQUEST_ID' value='044CC083-615E-0439-7F42-BD1959FA427A'></input>"
                                postFormHtml += "<input type='hidden' name='CHECKSUM' value='3CFC33AD6B713A57E783F53FF0A96CE2'></input>"

Comment: `self.dpoParamArr.forEach {  postFormHtml += "<input type='hidden' name='\($0.key)' value='\($0.value)'></input>" }` should do the trick then. But it'd be nice to add your end-goal to your question by editing it, not only in comment.

Comment: I get an error "Value of tuple type '(String, JSON)' has no member 'key'"

Comment: That's because I don't know what's `JSON`. Where is it coming from?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226236/discussion-between-sebastien-desemberg-and-larme).

Comment: If this has been resolved then please remove the question.

Comment: It has not and will add answer when I have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's look like you are using Alamofire with SwiftyJSON. Below is some simple way to convert json to swift array.

1.Convert Json array to swift array.

```
            if let swiftArray = self.dpoParamArr.arrayObject as? [[String:Any]] {
                
                // swiftArray is array of dictionary
                for item in swiftArray {

                    // item is a dictionary and you will get its value by key 
                    // here how to get value by key
                    
                    let name = item["name"] as? String
                    let value = item["value"] as? String
                    
                    //printing the values
                    print("Name is: ", name)
                    print("Value is: ", value)
                    print("=========================")
                }
            }
```

2. You can also use like below

   ```
            for item in self.dpoParamArr.arrayValue {

                //here how to get value by key
                let name = item["name"].stringValue
                let value = item["value"].stringValue

                //printing the values
                print("Name is: ", name)
                print("Value is: ", value)
                print("=========================")
            }
   ```

You can use SwiftyJSON for parsing. SwiftyJSON is a simplified JSON parsing library that gives you clearer syntax than the built-in iOS libraries. To detail information please read its [document](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)